# Row distribution using Foundation framework

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I need this distribution, i'm using Foundation framework, I tried this but doesn't work.

[image: Mockup]

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="small-6 large-2 columns">Logo</div>
       <div class="small-12 large-8 columns">menu</div>
       <div class="small-6 large-2 columns">Another logo</div>
    </div>
```

How I can get it?

Comment: maybe you can go with a topnavbar with integrated logo that collapses on small devices: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html

Comment: Is not a navbar, I need it like another column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the image on the left is desktop and on the right is mobile, you need to use the push and pull presentational classes to accomplish this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="small-12 large-8 columns push-2">
    <ul class="inline-list">
      <li><a href="">Lorem.</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Nisi.</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Quas?</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Tempora.</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Quaerat!</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="small-6 large-2 columns pull-8"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x600&text=logo1" alt=""></div>
   <div class="small-6 large-2 columns"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x600&text=logo2" alt=""></div>
</div>
```